# [Theano]TypeError: cost must be a scalar

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, regularized

I am undergoing a research project that requires me to write a regularizer for a DNN.

```
import lasagne
from lasagne.nonlinearities import leaky_rectify, softmax
import theano, theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets, sklearn.preprocessing, sklearn.model_selection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tabulate import tabulate
import time
import math



#psi function that will be used in the penalty function
def psi(g,l): 
    m = g.shape[1]
    C = (1/T.pow(2,m))*(1/T.pow(math.pi,((m-1)/2))) / (T.gamma((m+1)/2))
    logDens = T.log(C) + m*T.log(l) - l*T.sqrt(T.sum(g**2))
    dens = T.exp(logDens)
    return(dens)

#pstar function that will be used in the penalty function
def pStar(g,lambda1,lambda0,theta):
    psi1 = psi(g,lambda1)
    psi0 = psi(g,lambda0)
    ## if a coefficient is really large then both these will numerically be zero 
    if theta*psi1 ==0 and (1-theta)*psi0==0:
        p = 1
    else:
        p = (theta*psi1) / (theta*psi1 + (1 - theta)*psi0)           
    return p
    
#Seperable 
def pen_S(l):
    theta = 0.5
    lambda1 = 1
    lambda0 = 12
    for j in range(len(l)):
        t = l[j]
        m = t.shape[1]
        n = t.shape[0].eval()
        cost = T.zeros((1,1))            
        for i in range(n):
            g = t[i]
            temp = -lambda1*T.sum(g**2) + T.log(pStar(T.zeros((1,m)),lambda1,lambda0,theta)/pStar(g,lambda1,lambda0,theta))
            cost = cost + temp
    return cost 
    
# Number of simulations
N_runs = 1

# Maximum number of epochs
max_epochs = 1500

# Define number of layers and number of neurons
H_layers = np.asarray([40, 20])

# Minibatch size
batch_size = 300

# Lasagne Regularizers to be tested
regularizers = [pen_S]

# Define the regularization factors for each algorithm
reg_factors = [10**-3.5]

# Define the names (for display purposes)
names = ['SSGL_Sep']

# Load the dataset (DIGITS)
digits = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
X = digits.data
y = digits.target

# MNIST
#mnist = sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='C:/Users/ISPAMM/Downloads')
#X = mnist.data
#y = mnist.target

# Preprocessing (input)
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Output structures
tr_errors = np.zeros((len(regularizers), N_runs))
tst_errors = np.zeros((len(regularizers), N_runs))
tr_times = np.zeros((len(regularizers), N_runs))
tr_obj = np.zeros((len(regularizers), N_runs, max_epochs))
sparsity_weights = np.zeros((len(regularizers), N_runs, len(H_layers)+1))
sparsity_neurons = np.zeros((len(regularizers), N_runs, len(H_layers)+1))

# Define the input and output symbolic variables
input_var = T.matrix(name='X')
target_var = T.ivector(name='y')

# Utility function for minibatches
def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]

for k in np.arange(0, N_runs):
    
    print("Run ", k+1, " of ", N_runs, "...\n", end="")

    # Split the data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

    # Define the network structure
    network = lasagne.layers.InputLayer((None, X.shape[1]), input_var)
    for h in H_layers:
        network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(network, h, nonlinearity=leaky_rectify, W=lasagne.init.GlorotNormal())
    network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(network, len(np.unique(y)), nonlinearity=softmax, W=lasagne.init.GlorotNormal())
    params_original = lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(network)    
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
    
    # Define the loss function
    prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
    loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)

    # Define the test function
    test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network, deterministic=True)
    test_acc = T.mean(T.eq(T.argmax(test_prediction, axis=1), target_var),
                          dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    test_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], test_acc, allow_input_downcast=True)    
    
     
    for r in np.arange(0, len(regularizers)):
        
        # Set to original parameters
        lasagne.layers.set_all_param_values(network, params_original)        
        
        # Define the regularized loss function
        loss_reg = loss.mean() + reg_factors[r] * lasagne.regularization.regularize_network_params(network, regularizers[r])
    
        # Update function
        # updates_reg = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss_reg, params,learning_rate=0.01)
        updates_reg = lasagne.updates.adam(loss_reg, params)
        
        # Training function
        train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss_reg, updates=updates_reg, allow_input_downcast=True)
    
        # Train network
        print("\tTraining with ", names[r], " regularization, epoch: ", end="")
        start = time.time()
        for epoch in range(max_epochs):
            loss_epoch = 0
            batches = 0
            if np.mod(epoch, 10) == 0:
                print(epoch, "... ", end="")
            for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train, y_train, batch_size, shuffle=True):
                input_batch, target_batch = batch
                loss_epoch += train_fn(input_batch, target_batch)
                batches += 1
            tr_obj[r,k,epoch] = loss_epoch/batches
        end = time.time()
        tr_times[r,k] = end - start
        print(epoch, ".")
        
        # Final test with accuracy
        print("\tTesting the network with ", names[r], " regularization...")
        tr_errors[r,k] = test_fn(X_train, y_train)
        tst_errors[r,k] = test_fn(X_test, y_test)
        
        # Check sparsity
        params_trained = lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(network, trainable=True)
        sparsity_weights[r,k,:] = [1-(x.round(decimals=3).ravel().nonzero()[0].shape[0]/x.size) for x in params_trained[0::2]]
        sparsity_neurons[r,k,:] = [x.round(decimals=3).sum(axis=1).nonzero()[0].shape[0] for x in params_trained[0::2]]

tr_obj_mean = np.mean(tr_obj, axis=1)

# Plot the average loss
plt.figure()
plt.title('Training objective')
for r in np.arange(0, len(regularizers)):
    plt.semilogy(tr_obj_mean[r, :], label=names[r])
plt.legend()

# Print the results
print(tabulate([['Tr. accuracy [%]'] + np.mean(tr_errors, axis=1).round(decimals=4).tolist(), 
                ['Test. accuracy [%]'] + np.mean(tst_errors, axis=1).round(decimals=4).tolist(), 
                ['Tr. times [secs.]'] + np.mean(tr_times, axis=1).round(decimals=4).tolist(), 
                ['Sparsity [%]'] + np.mean(sparsity_weights, axis=1).round(decimals=4).tolist(),
                ['Neurons'] + np.mean(sparsity_neurons, axis=1).round(decimals=4).tolist()],
                headers=['']+names))
```

Here is my defined regularizer pen_S(l), but when I run the code to train the network, i was promted with 'TypeError: cost must be a scalar.' But I think my output of pen_S is already a scalar.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this a rare bug or happens on every run?  If latter, could you try to use debugger to inspect and verify the type is correct?  Sometimes I avoid debugger and just print: `print(type(cost))` or `print(dir(cost))` or `print(cost)`

Comment: How hard is it to offer a piece of code that can be copied to a file and can be executed ? Because as for now I can't reproduce the error. You could surround your code by a `try...except` block and drop the error.

Comment: @areop-enap Hi, I have edited my codes that can be executed. Sorry for that.

Comment: @RazzleShazl I have tried print(type(cost)) and it gives <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>. Is it okay to have cost in scalar TensorVariable? If yes, how could I check whether this TensorVariable is a scalar? Thank you very much!